# Fastapi consuming live messages

Tags: python, websocket, rabbitmq, fastapi

I have a virtual assistant which receives messages and send it to a event broker (e.g rabbitmq).

An event broker allows me to connect my running assistant to other services that process the data coming in from conversations.

Example:

If I have a RabbitMQ server running, as well as another application that consumes the events, then this consumer needs to implement Pika's start_consuming() method with a callback action. Here's a simple example:

```
import json
import pika


def _callback(self, ch, method, properties, body):
        # Do something useful with your incoming message body here, e.g.
        # saving it to a database
        print('Received event {}'.format(json.loads(body)))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # RabbitMQ credentials with username and password
    credentials = pika.PlainCredentials('username', 'password')

    # Pika connection to the RabbitMQ host - typically 'rabbit' in a
    # docker environment, or 'localhost' in a local environment
    connection = pika.BlockingConnection(
        pika.ConnectionParameters('rabbit', credentials=credentials))

    # start consumption of channel
    channel = connection.channel()
    channel.basic_consume(_callback,
                          queue='events',
                          no_ack=True)
    channel.start_consuming()
```

What is the correct way to use fastapi with Pika to consume these live messages and saving it to a database ?

Do I need a websocket route ?